# the sum of closed convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis

Let C and D be two closed convex subsets of a Banach space with C+D is closed. If bounded sequence $\{x_n\}\subset C+D$, can we choose bounded sequences $\{c_n\}\subset C$ and $\{d_n\}\subset D$ such that $x_n=c_n+d_n$ for every n.

Comment: I like the question! Did you already find some answer or a counterexample to it?